# How can I save/print values in my WATCH list in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

When I attach the Visual Studio 2008 debugger to my web server process, I sometimes browse a large amount of data in my watch list.  Suppose I have an array of string variable that I expand to show 20 entries.  It seems that the only way to save these values is to copy and paste them one at a time.  I have gone so far as to do a screen-shot in order to have a record of what the values were (to refer to later or print a hard copy).

Is there an easy way to save and print these values?  I am familiar with the new "IntelliTrace" feature in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, but it seems overkill for this purpose.

I just want to take something like an array of strings and save it for later reference once I've stopped the debugger.

What's a good way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Select the entries in the Watch window (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: 23 seconds...dammit. I defer to your trigger finger. I am Red Dead defeated.

Comment: Thanks!  Somehow, I didn't see that you can select multiple values and copy the whole thing.