# Is there any way to export the contents of the watch window in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there any way to export the contents of the watch window in VS2010 similar to exporting break points. I need to be able to export the complete contents of the watch window(including all sub nodes) to a file.

Comment: Method 1:Alt-printscreen.  It will give you a bit map that you can paste in paint and then save to a file.

Comment: Method 2: highlight all the contents of the watch window (ctrl A), right click, select copy.  Open up notepad and paste.

Comment: vote for it via https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4139876-export-save-watch

Comment: also possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3064189/80428

Answer (score 3):

I doubt it is possible to export contents of the watch window.

Alternative way - Export the datatips.
1. In a source window, place the mouse pointer over any variable in the current scope. A DataTip appears.
2. Right-click on a variable, then click Pin to source.
3. On the Debug menu, click Export/Import DataTips.

Comment: This does not export the contents of the pinned variable apparently, only the pinned state itself so that you may restore it later for future debug sessions I assume, like a 'display' associated to the source code.

Comment: For arrays, you may open the view. From within the pane, there's an 'Export to CSV' button that might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just wanting to save the aOn the watch window, click on the root/parent object, right-click -> select all.

Then Copy and paste into blank excel workbook.

Answer (score 0):

There is a visual studio extension available [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarElabd.ObjectExporter).
Please take a look it as well.

If it does not help, then please follow below steps:

*The goal is to write the variable values one by one to immediate window and copy from there to excel sheet.*

**#1.** When the breakpoint hits, Menu ->Debug->Windows->Immediate(Or Ctrl+Alt+I in VS2019)

**#2.** Type the variable name, IntelliSense will list all of the properties of this root variable. Get the value of each and copy/paste to excel sheet.
Hope it will helps.

Thanks.